# How to run PowerShell task on TFS Linux agent?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, tfsbuild

I have a release pipeline in TFS 2017, which runs on Linux agent and has Docker and PowerShell tasks. However Docker tasks are working fine but PowerShell tasks are failing because there is no .Net Framework installed.

What is the way to run PowerShell task on Linux agent or how to install .Net Framework on Linux agent?

Comment: Hi Naveen, is there any update? Can Daniel's answer resolve your issue?

Comment: Hi @LanceLi-MSFT I am still working on this facing some issues once done I will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS 2017 predates support for PowerShell Core, which is cross-platform and runs on Linux. So the built-in PowerShell task is going to be useless for this scenario.

However, you can still run a PowerShell script on your Linux agent, you'll just have to use a Command Line task to call `pwsh`. Naturally, you'll have to ensure that PowerShell Core is installed on your Linux agent.

Upgrading to a more recent version of TFS will also include an updated PowerShell task that includes a checkbox for "Use PowerShell Core", which will also solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel I will try this.

Comment: I have called pwsh then in context ran all the commands.